# How to post a feed item in friend's wall via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-friends

I am making a very simple gift application on Facebook. The main problem here is how to notify the user which don't use the application about the fact that his friend send him a gift?

As the Notifications are disabled on old REST API and `stream.publish` will not work on the friends who didn't authorize to post on their wall, I am confused.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST["ids"]) ) {
    $friends = ( isset($_REQUEST["ids"]) ) ? $_REQUEST["ids"] : 0;

    if (empty($_POST['giftname']) ) {
        $gname = '1.gif';
    } else {
        $gname = $this->input->post('giftname');
    }
    //$this->app_model->send_gift( $user, $friends, $gname,$facebook );
    //$this->app_model->send_gift( $user, $friends, $gname,$facebook );
    $to=$friends;
    $from=$user;
    $gift=$gname;

    $total_send=count($friends);

    for ($x=0; $x<$total_send; $x++ ) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO gifts (`giftfrom`, `giftto`, `gname`) VALUES( $from, $to[$x], \"$gift\" )");

        try {
            // Send notification
            //$facebook->api_client->notifications_send($to[$x], 'sent you a gift using <a href="http://apps.facebook.com/tsaxikner/">Հայկական Նվերներ</a>. <a href="http://apps.facebook.com/tsaxikner/">Ստանալ Նվերը</a>.');

            // Publish feed story
            $feed_body = '<fb:userlink uid="'.$from.'" shownetwork="false"/>-ը նվեր է ուղարկել <fb:name uid="'.$to[$x].'"/>-ին  <a href="http://apps.facebook.com/tsaxikner/">Հայկական Նվերներ</a>-ի միջոցով.';

            $feed_body = 'Ստուգեք <a href="http://apps.facebook.com/tsaxikner/"> <fb:name uid="'.$to[$x].'" firstnameonly="true" possessive="true"/> Հայկական Նվերներ</a>.';

            //$facebook->api_client->feed_publishActionOfUser($feed_title, $feed_body);
            $facebook->api_client->make_wall_post($user,$to[$x],$feed_body);
            $facebook->api_client->notifications_sendEmail($user, 'You have a gift', $feed_body, $fbml);

            //$facebook_graph->api('' $message, null, null, $target_id );
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    // end of for
}
```

I use FBML

Comment: We are able to send post on fb-wall by php-sdk now. Check my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I can post on the user's friends walls via the PHP API.

Try this :

```
$facebook->api('/[FRIEND_ID]/feed', 'post', array(
          'message' => 'test message',
          'link' => 'http://google.com',
          'name' => 'test name',
          'caption' => 'test caption',
          'description' => 'test long description',
      ));
```

Comment: It's important to know you will need `publish_actions, publish_stream` permissions.

Comment: @TomRoggero: Yeah. We need those 2 permissions 2 post feed item.

Comment: @MrGewa: Is this answer solving your problem? If yes, mark it accepted. Else what do you next required.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a [request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests) would be a more appropriate (and effective) channel for this communication. With a request you have the added benefit of the [notification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#notifications) that will be automatically generated along with your request. You can very easily send requests using the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

To answer your original question though, as long as you have the "publish_stream" [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) and the user whose access token you're using is allowed to post on the recipient's wall (that's a privacy setting that could be set), all you need to do is issue a POST request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER2ID/feed?link=YOURLINK
```

(You can find the parameters for posting a feed story [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed).) If you're using the PHP SDK, make sure you upgrade to [version 3](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) (it's [required](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/) that you upgrade by September 1st anyways).

Answer (score 1):

Its no longer possible. You need to use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to post on another persons wall directly. If you want to invite them to user your app you will have to use the request-form-submit fbml tag. You can find this here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form-submit. After that user has allowed your app you can then post on their wall.

Comment: We are able to send post on fb-wall by php-sdk now. Check my answer.